# ¿Qué formas coloquiales para referirse a un jefe existen en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, sustantivos

Hace poco aprendí una palabra curiosa en inglés, que salía en una de las canciones de la banda sonora de *[Hércules](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119282/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)*, de Disney.

> **[honcho](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/honcho)**
>
> <sup><sub>**noun** [ C ] mainly US informal</sub></sup>
>
> **the person in charge**

Me resultó curiosa la palabra, y más aún [su etimología](https://www.etymonline.com/word/honcho#etymonline_v_12136): viene del japonés *hancho*, con el significado de "líder de un grupo", y se importó de allí a finales de la década de 1940. He visto también que en inglés británico su equivalente sería *[gaffer](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/diccionario/ingles/gaffer)*.

Visto lo visto, me preguntaba pues: ¿qué palabra podríamos usar para traducir *honcho*, de forma que se mantenga el significado, y se aluda coloquialmente a un jefe o responsable, pero sin que resulte despectivo o irónico? (Y que se pueda usar en una película de Disney...)

Comment: To the annoyance of pedants most English speakers refer to _head honcho_ when as you correctly state a _honcho_ is the head already.

Comment: In Argentina we sometimes use "capo".

Comment: @Gustavson Keeping im mind that if someone "es un capo", he's not the boss but someone very good at... whatever we are talking about.

Comment: @Gaviota I agree, but if you use the definite article, then "the boss" will be understood, e.g. Ahí viene el capo de la empresa.

Comment: @Gustavson Yes, no doubt. With "the" it's generally the boss. Without, it's probably the awesome genius :D

Comment: capo es italiano, por eso se dice en Argentina. Tienen mucho del italiano.

Answer (score 4):

En algunos lugares también se usa la palabra "patrón" para referirse al jefe

Answer (score 0):

O [**gerifalte**](https://dle.rae.es/gerifalte):

> 5. m. y f. coloq. Jefe, autoridad. U. m. en sent. irón.